# Multiple select value if statement jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have 2 select menus and i'm trying to compare a selected value of one with another but I cannot get the conditional statement working, please see my comments in my code below and in the jsFiddle.

Here's my code and a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvbj2dmm/1/):

The expected value from the `#purpose` select menu is "5". The `var selected` is my attempt at grabbing that value from the `#purpose` select menu.

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function() {
   if ( this.value == '8') {
      $("#business").show();
      $("#investor-type").hide();
   } else {
      $("#business").hide();
      $("#investor-type").show();
   }
});

var selected = $("#purpose option:selected", this).val();

$('#investor-type').on('change', function() {
   if ( this.value == '1') {
      $("#disclaimer-form").show();
      $(".disclaimer-content").show();
   // Having trouble with this else if below
   } else if ( this.value == "2" && selected == "5") {
      $("#disclaimer-form").show();
      $(".disclaimer-content").show();
   } else {
      $("#disclaimer-form").hide();
      $(".disclaimer-content").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: "Having trouble with this else if below" is not a useful description. What is the expected and actual result? for example if the code is in an onload handler,  the var selected is not available inside the on change event - also what is the `this` in `var selected = $("#purpose option:selected", this).val();`

Comment: It's probably that you need to re-evaluate `selected` upon `change`.

Comment: @mplungjan Seems like an obvious answer to your question: To show a specific div when the two conditions are met. The selected var is my attempt at grabbing the value from the #purpose select menu. See the fiddle.

Comment: What is the expected value of `selected` and what is the ACTUAL value? Use console.log. My guess is that selected is not available when you are using it. It needs to be accessed inside the event handler. Now it is only accessed onload of the page

Comment: `$('#investor-type').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $("#purpose").val();` https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lea13zx1/

Comment: @mplungjan See updated question detailing answers to your questions

Comment: You need to update selected after purpose was changed.

Comment: please check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/z4kuwLod/#&togetherjs=FjwCqtEjqy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . move the selected inside the change

`$('#investor-type').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $("#purpose").val();`

2 . test the 5 inside the 2

`else if (this.value == "2") {
        $("#retailstatusyes").toggle(selected == "5");
        $("#retailstatusno").toggle(selected != "5");
        $("#prostatus").hide();
   }`

You also need to trigger the change of the investor type if the user changes the country.

Here is a full version with better var names using CSS to hide initially

```js
$(function() {
  // This shows the next select menu
  $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
    var other = this.value == '8';
    $("#noaccess").toggle(other);
    $("#investor-type").toggle(!other);
    $('#investor-type').change();
  });

  $('#investor-type').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $("#purpose").val(),
    isDutch = selected == "5", 
    isPro = this.value == "1",
    isRetail = this.value == "2";
    $("#prostatus").toggle(isPro);
    if (isRetail) {
      $("#retailstatusyes").toggle(isDutch);
      $("#retailstatusno").toggle(!isDutch);
    } 
    else {
      $("#retailstatusyes").hide();
      $("#retailstatusno").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.invtype {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="purpose" class="left">
  <option value="0">Please choose a country</option>
  <option value="1">Austria</option>
  <option value="2">France</option>
  <option value="3">Germany</option>
  <option value="4">Italy</option>
  <option value="5">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="6">Spain</option>
  <option value="7">Switzerland</option>
  <option value="8">Other</option>
</select>

<select id="investor-type" class="left" style="display:none;">
  <option value="0">Investor Type</option>
  <option value="1">Professional Investor</option>
  <option value="2">Retail Investor</option>
</select>


<div class="invtype" id="noaccess">
  You have selected Other and thus you cannot access the next select menu. Soz.
</div>

<div class="invtype" id="prostatus">
  You are a pro investor
</div>

<div class="invtype" id="retailstatusno">
  You are a retail investor but NOT from the Netherlands
</div>

<div class="invtype" id="retailstatusyes">
  You are a retail investor AND you are from the Netherlands. Congrats.
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

move the assignment of selected inside change of #investor-type. 
take look at this link

```
// This shows the next select menu
$('#purpose').on('change', function() {
 if ( this.value == '8') {
  $("#noaccess").show();
  $("#investor-type").hide();

  $("#prostatus").hide();
  $("#retailstatusyes").hide();
  $("#retailstatusno").hide();
} else {
  $("#noaccess").hide();
  $("#investor-type").show();
  $("#prostatus").hide();
  $("#retailstatusyes").hide();
  $("#retailstatusno").hide();
}
});

// Grab value from previous select menu for comparison
$('#investor-type').on('change', function() {
var selected = $("#purpose option:selected").val();
console.log(selected+" "+this.value);
if ( this.value == '1') {
  $("#prostatus").show();
} else if ( this.value == "2") {
 $("#retailstatusno").show();
 $("#prostatus").hide();
// Not working. Show specific success div if the current value is 2 and value from previous select is 5
} else if ( this.value == "2" && selected == "5") {
  $("#retailstatusyes").show();
  $("#prostatus").hide();
} else {
  $("#noaccess").hide();
  $("#prostatus").hide();
  $("#retailstatusyes").hide();
  $("#retailstatusno").hide();
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvbj2dmm/9/

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to move the evaluation of `selected` into the event handler to get the up-to-date value:

```
$('#investor-type').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $("#purpose option:selected").val();

    // ...
}
```

Secondly, the order of your `else if` is wrong because the first `(this.value == "2")` will render the next `(this.value == "2" && selected == "5")` useless. Try to change their order so that the most specific one will come first:

```
if (this.value == '1') {
  $("#prostatus").show();
} else if (this.value == "2" && selected == "5") {
  $("#retailstatusyes").show();
  $("#prostatus").hide();
} else if (this.value == "2") {
  $("#retailstatusno").show();
  $("#prostatus").hide();
} else {
  $("#noaccess").hide();
  $("#prostatus").hide();
  $("#retailstatusyes").hide();
  $("#retailstatusno").hide();
}
```

See modified [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvbj2dmm/2/)

Comment: I did not vote down, but the logic is not much improved.

Comment: @mplungjan, I would argue that explicitly checking for `2` and `5` is expressing the logic much clearer than first checking for `2` then a sub `if` that is checking `5`. Nevertheless, both approaches seem to work.

Comment: I will argue that this is simpler `if (this.value == "2") {
        $("#retailstatusyes").toggle(selected == "5");        $("#retailstatusno").toggle(selected != "5");`

Comment: @mplungjan, I will further argue that there are many ways to improve the code using basic jQuery techniques, but it has nothing to do with the actual problem.